# Can't connect to proxy IP with node.js/puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, vpn

I've double checked that the IP in question works. I can ping to it and everything. But when I try to do

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--proxy-server=' + ip]});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
```

it doesn't connect. The IP doesn't have a port, if that helps. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the proxy server will be having a port on which it will be running:
the default port is 8080,
Try specifying the port in the IP and connecting.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--proxy-server=' + ip + ':8080']});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
```

If still not working you can configure a auto detect proxy setting as follows:
--proxy-auto-detect

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--proxy-auto-detect']});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
```